# Best approach to identify unique posts with different fields

Tags: algorithm, duplicates

We collect posts for certain websites every day and we want to save posts in our database without duplicated or missing posts.

We collect every day all posts from a link and after this, we apply a filter to save it in our database. The challenge is to build resilient filter criteria.

The post may have the following attributes:

- Title
- Text content
- User
- Published date
- Discovered date (this date is stamped by us when we collect the posts)

**Conditions**

1. Any of the above property can miss from a source website **and even for the same website at a different time.**
2. Any of the fields may be alternated in time at a certain moment. We want to detect this to avoid duplicates.
3. Some posts may have a very short text (e.g. “Super”) and no user. In this case, we don’t want to have a false-positive in duplicate detection mechanism.
4. In time extra fields may appear and we want to keep the possibility of comparison stored posts with new posts (with extra fields).

**E.G.**

**Same posts at different time moments:**

```
{title:”test”, content:”this is a test post”, user: “”, publishedDate:0, discoveredDate: 1573591568}

{title:”test”, content:”this is a test post. John”, user: “”, publishedDate:0, discoveredDate: 1573591999}

{title:"test", content:"this is a test post.\n John", user: "John", publishedDate:0, discoveredDate: 1573599999}
```

**Different posts:**

```
{title:"simple", content:"simple", user: "", publishedDate:0, discoveredDate: 1573591568}

{title:"simple", content:"simple", user: "", publishedDate:1573591568, discoveredDate: 1573591568}
```

**Our current approach**
At this moment we create a hash signature using title and content but this is not enough to cover all the above cases.

Comment: What programming language are you using?  What code are you currently using in your current approach?  Why aren't you including the other fields you mention (besides title and content) in your hash?  Is it somehow too difficult to do?

Comment: I am using python, but the code is not so relevant here. 
At the moment I started we collected just title and content as fields. In time some websites are adding extra fields and I want to cover this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding content (not just string) comparison the following links might be useful:

https://chairnerd.seatgeek.com/fuzzywuzzy-fuzzy-string-matching-in-python/
https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy